# Git: gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function

Tags: git

I got the error when using *git pull* command

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/path/to/repo.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

I try many methods from Internet but they're unuseful. Also, tried to deal with proxy in my network.

My PC: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x86_64

Does it have any effective ways to resolve the problem ?

Note: There're some solutions https://devopscube.com/gnutls-handshake-failed-aws-codecommit/ or https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: It happened with me when `https://github.com` was blocked by my firewall

Comment: I somehow solved this without any install, and only by resetting my connection (4G smartphone access point): put laptop in airplane mode, put phone in airplane mode, restart phone access point, reconnect laptop to the latter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My server is behind a proxy and I got the same error, I solved this modifying ~/.gitconfig adding the proxy conf:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp
```

Answer (score 41):

I resolved this problem by-

```
 apt-get -y install build-essential nghttp2 libnghttp2-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: could you explain a little more?

Comment: Apparently the problem is with libssl, because after I installed `libssl-dev`, the problem was solved. Before that, I had `libssl1.0-dev`.

Comment: The package 'libssl-dev' is the magic, but why? Only some repo can't be checked out.

Comment: Worked, but please explain why it worked.

Answer (score 12):

I received the same error verbatim using git in Windows-WSL2/Ubuntu

In my case it was resolved when I dropped my corporate VPN connection and resumed using git successfully and immediately.

To verify that as causation rather than correlation, I reconnected to the VPN and tried again and it broke again; then dropped VPN the second time - lo and behold it worked

Hope that helps someone out there!

Comment: I too had my VPN turned on & faced this error. Once I tried to disconnect the VPN & tried cloning again, it worked!

Comment: Same setup, same problem. It worked when I stopped GlobalProtect. But why? I haven't had any problems with cloning from github or gitlab (public versions). The error occurred when a script was trying to clone a repo from 'https://go.googlesource.com/mod/'

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this by updating git to the lasted version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: This works like a charm, especially you have Ubuntu 16 or older

Answer (score 2):

I solve this by running this command in WSL: `sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1400`

reference: [Git and gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function errror](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5346)

Comment: This simple tricks solved the problem. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great solution :

Just create a ssh key and add them to your github acc

help:
[Create ssh key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) On this page, first select your operating system, then follow the steps

[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Finally, clone the repos with ssh link, not with http

Comment: This is the permanent solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i'm cloning the git project.
cloning url port & browser displayed url port in the project are shows different url ports.
hence i used browser displayed url port to cloning the project & i could clone the project successfully

Answer (score 0):

[**I had a problem like yours, and I gave an alternative to solve it, the steps are:

1. make sure to log in as super admin in UBUNTU terminal
2. try to repeat the push/pull command in your GIT
3. You will be asked to provide your github email and password (starting August 13, 2021 you will have to change the password with a token)
4. create a personal token in your GIT, you can see the doc at https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ **][screenshot my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E5P4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who is going to believe me but for me, I restarted my terminal and everything was good again, am also using ubuntu, I know most of you won't believe me but it worked for me.
So just restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in wsl2 ubuntu
the following solution solved my problem .

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5346#issuecomment-1016469312

https://serverfault.com/questions/1059522/meraki-vpn-behind-nat-breaks-bitbucket-git-on-wsl2-ubuntu-20-on-windows-10

check both links.