# Git, fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/path/to/repo.git': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 in a windows VirtualBox (the Stanford CS144 lab
  VM) (and I am not a Stanford student doing homework, just for fun)
- Git Version: 2.32.0

And when I run this:
`$ git push -u origin master`

I got an error:`> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/path/to/repo/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.`

[I have tried the methods from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379234/git-gnutls-handshake-failed-error-in-the-pull-function/54178424), and it didn't work out.

One of the methods in the above link:

```
$ mkdir ~/git-rectify
$ cd ~/git-rectify
$ sudo apt-get source git
$ sudo apt-get update
$ apt-get source git
$ sudo apt-get build-dep git
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
$ dpkg-source -x git_x.x.x-1ubuntu0.1
$ sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
$ sudo dpkg -i git_x.x.x.x-1_amd64.deb
```

I ran the sixth line:
`$ sudo apt-get build-dep git`

After running, I got the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:git : Depends: gettext but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but it is not installable
                 Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not installable
                 Depends: subversion but it is not installable
                 Depends: libsvn-perl but it is not installable
                 Depends: libyaml-perl but it is not installable
                 Depends: tcl but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcgi-pm-perl but it is not installable
                 Depends: libmailtools-perl but it is not installable
                 Depends: cvs but it is not installable
                 Depends: cvsps but it is not installable
                 Depends: libdbd-sqlite3-perl but it is not installable
                 Depends: libio-pty-perl but it is not installable
                 Depends: debhelper (>= 9) but it is not installable
                 Depends: dh-exec (>= 0.7) but it is not installable
                 Depends: dh-apache2 but it is not installable
                 Depends: asciidoc (>= 8.6.10) but it is not installable
                 Depends: xmlto but it is not installable
                 Depends: docbook-xsl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced this problem when I clone any repo from GitHub or create any new repo. After working in the repo when I push my changes or going to push my new work repo to GitHub I get this error. I think this happens when your GitHub account is not configured globally with your Linux machine.

You can use `$ git push -u origin master --force` this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You sources.list is misconfigured, edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`  as follows:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner

deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse  
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get build-dep git
```

Comment: Actually, I have already done that, and it didn't work.